# MAX() for 2 Dates Separately

Tags: sql, db2, max

I am trying to find a way to get the Max Date from one field and then to remove duplication get the Max of those dates from another field.
So far I have managed to get the Max of the Effective Dates, but need to get the Max timestamp from those values to remove duplication.
Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    a2.CUST_ID
    , Address
    , Effective_Date             --DATE variable
    , Timestamp_Entry            --DATETIME variable 

    FROM
        (SELECT
        CUST_ID
        , MAX (Effective_Date) as Most_Effective_Date
        FROM  Address_Table
        GROUP BY CUST_ID) a1

    JOIN Address_Table a2
    ON a1.CUST_ID = a2.CUST_ID and a1.Most_Effective_Date = a2.Effective_Date
```

(Some timestamp entrys may be newer entries with older effective date, which is why the Effective Date takes priority, and then the TimeStamp should remove duplicates

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I don't get what getting the maximum from two columns has to do with duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cust_id order by effective_date desc, timestamp_entry desc) as seqnum
      from address_table a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns the "most recent" address for each customer based on the two columns.

Comment: That's it, Thank you!